# decomposition of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

my professor uses this decomposition all the time and I don't know why it's allowed.
he told me it's true for any square matrix (I assume any real matrix).

why can I decompose any square matrix A, to:
$$
A=UΛU^{-1}
$$
where U is invertible and Λ is a diagonal matrix with A's eigenvalues on its diagonal.

shouldn't A be diagnolizable to do that?
he just insists that it's true for ANY square matrix A, without any other requirements, and I do not wish risk arguing too much with him.

Comment: You are correct that the matrix needs to be diagonalizable, and not all square matrices are: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix

Comment: That said, he may be confusing diagonal form with the related Jordan-normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form.

Comment: It is indeed false in general. However did your professor mention whether the matrix is symmetric ? Because real symmetric matrices are always diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually true if the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable. Such a decomposition always exists for any square **complex** matrix but $\Lambda$ is in this case only triangular. $\Lambda$ is guaranteed to be diagonal if and only if $A$ is [hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix). This is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Your professor's claim is correct if $A$ is supposed to be symmetric ([spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)). This is the only class of **real** matrices that has the property of being systematically diagonalizable.

Comment: I agree that the matrix needs to be diagonalizable, but I disagree with the fact that matrix $A$ needs to be symmetric. For example, consider the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix},$ with eigenvalues $0,1$.

Then, there is a matrix $U = \begin{bmatrix}1&-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
0& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}  \end{bmatrix},$
such that:
$$A = U\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot U^{-1}.$$

Clearly, $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: I meant symmetric matrices are the only class of real matrices to be systematically diagonalizable, by theorem. Sorry if this was unclear, I'm editing my answer to fix this.

Comment: There are other common classes of matrices that are "systematically diagonalizable".  For example, the set of $n \times n$ matrices with $n$ distinct eigenvalues, and (over the complex numbers) the set of normal matrices.